# Pushing array to vector gives error

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I'm trying to fill a vector with some arrays. 
What's wrong with this code?

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    double p[10]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    vector<double[10]> p_prev;

    p_prev.push_back(p);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling it with `g++` `-std=c++11`.

```
error: request for member '~ double[10]' in '* __p', which is of non-class type 'double[10]'
```

How do I properly push it?

Comment: Don't. Use an `std::array<double, 10>`. That is both copyable and assignable.

Comment: I agree that this question is a duplicate. Didn't realize it although browsed through the related questions... Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays don't fullfill the requirements for container elements. Try std::array:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    std::array<double, 10> p{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    vector<std::array<double, 10> > p_prev;

    p_prev.push_back(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought if I have using namespace std, array is equivalent to std::array. So, this is the difference between <double, 10> and [10], right?

Comment: @sashkello They're two totally unrelated types.  C style arrays do *not* have type `std::array`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot store C-style arrays in a `vector` or any other container. Because for a type to be stored in `vector`, it needs to be "assignable", but C-style arrays do not fulfill that.

Use `std::array` instead.

Comment: It doesn't need a copy constructor (`int` doesn't have one, `std::auto_ptr` does); it needs to be "Copyable" and "Assignable" (or "Movable", in C++11).  C style arrays are neither.